# Better way to resize images

Tags: android, bitmap

I've been researching but I've not found anything good. Is there a way to resize images retrieved from a remote resource without the image losing quality? As for now, I do not have anything to resize my images. I just added `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` within my xml.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for an image to be resized without losing quality are vectorized images.

Comment: So how do I change bitmap to a vectorized image? Or how would I implement it so that the Image View displays a vectorized image?

Comment: haven't done myself yet (but i'm actually planning on doing it quite soon) this might help:
http://vectormagic.com/home

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/10/displaying-svg-images-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)? It's a powerful image loader, simple and easy to use. Below code is an example of how to use it.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .resize(width, height)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView);
```